# Facebook error "Missing redirect_uri parameter."

Tags: php, facebook, kohana

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Error fetching remote 
    https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
                client_id=<removed>&
                client_secret=<remove>&
                code=<remove>&
                redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F<ip>%2Flogin%3Fmethod%3Dfboauth%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F<ip>%252F 

[ status 400 ] {"error":{"type":"OAuthException",
                         "message":"Missing redirect_uri parameter."}}
```

Even though I'm included redirect_uri, Facebook Connect is reporting otherwise.

Comment: Test a shorter redirect_uri, such as http://<ip>/login; perhaps Facebook is choking on the double-encoded parameters. Also make sure that your firewall allows outgoing connections on port 443.

Comment: Outbound connections on port 443 were blocked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F%2F

There are three %2F in that redirect_uri, meaning three forward slashes:  http:///

I am not sure how you are building it, but you should check to see what would cause that extra slash.